# Animating sidemenu on hover

Tags: javascript, css

I want to show only the icons as default and on hover slide the sidemenu to the current state you see in the jsfiddle

Thanks in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/228/

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="profile-menu d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
            <div class="sidebar-item">
                <a class="d-flex" href="/">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-home" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 20px"></i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-item">
                <a class="d-flex" href="/profile">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-user-o" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 22px"></i>
                    <span>Profile</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-item">
                <a class="d-flex" href="/profile/messages">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-envelope-o" style="margin-right: 19px"></i>
                    <span>Messages</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not clear what you're saying

Comment: i want the sidemenu to show only the icons like this https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/250/ and on hover to show the original jsfiddle i posted

Comment: both fiddles are same

Comment: can u check again please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by changing navbars values on hover like this:

```css
    #sidebar {
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        font-weight: 500;
        border-right: 1px solid #797979;
        padding-top: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1000;
        width: 65px;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #2c2c2c;
        transition:1s;
    }
    #sidebar:hover{
      width: 259px;
    }
    #sidebar:hover .sidebar-item span{
      opacity:1;
    }
    .sidebar-item {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    }
    .sidebar-item span{
      opacity:0;
      transition:1s;
    }
    .sidebar-active {
        border-left: 5px solid #b1a0ff;
        color: #b1a0ff;
        background: #474747;
    }
    .sidebar-item a {
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="profile-menu d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
                <div class="sidebar-item">
                    <a class="d-flex" href="/">
                        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-home" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 20px"></i>
                        <span>Home</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-item">
                    <a class="d-flex" href="/profile">
                        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-user-o" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 22px"></i>
                        <span>Profile</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-item">
                    <a class="d-flex" href="/profile/messages">
                        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-envelope-o" style="margin-right: 19px"></i>
                        <span>Messages</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: exacly what i wanted, ty

Answer (score 1):

So from the comments this wasn't exactly what you were after but I put this together and might as well share it here anyway.

It animates the label in on hover using relative position and CSS transition. It does involve some changes to the HTML.

https://jsfiddle.net/Chipmo/111dd0sj/1/

```css
#sidebar {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-right: 1px solid #797979;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 259px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #2c2c2c;
}

.sidebar-item {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidebar-item a {
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar-item i {}

.sidebar-left-cover {
  background: #2c2c2c;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.sidebar-item .sidebar-label {
  position: relative;
  right: 100px;
  transition: right 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sidebar-item:hover .sidebar-label {
  right: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="profile-menu d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
      <div class="sidebar-item">
        <a class="d-flex" href="/">
          <div class="sidebar-left-cover">

            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-home" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 20px"></i></div>
          <span class="sidebar-label">Home</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-item">
        <a class="d-flex" href="/profile">
          <div class="sidebar-left-cover">

            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-user-o" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 22px"></i>
          </div>
          <span class="sidebar-label">Profile</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-item">
        <a class="d-flex" href="/profile/messages">
          <div class="sidebar-left-cover">

            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-envelope-o" style="margin-right: 19px"></i></div>
          <span class="sidebar-label">Messages</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```